# Subscript error in arrays with p column

Tags: equations, arrays

I'm having trouble putting equations into an array with the `p{}` column options. Basically, with the `l`, `c` and `r` preambles there is no problem and we can type any equation we want:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
E = mc^2 & F = ma
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

However, once I specify the `p{}` option, subscripts and superscripts are no longer allowed. So this gives an error:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
E = mc^2 & F = ma
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

Any idea what is going on here and how to fix this?

Comment: `p{ }` requires a length as an argument. This being said, why don't you simply add some length between the two  parts of the equation?

Comment: What's the purpose of p type column in this specific array. Please explain.

Comment: `array` is not a suitable environment for displayed equations, it is designed for matrices of values and sets all the entries in inline textstyle math not in display style. but `p{}` should be `p{5cm}`

Comment: I just kept it generic without specifying the length, but the same problem happens with p{5cm} (I've now edited the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` column specification places the contents within a `\parbox`, which switches to text mode. So to typeset mathematics within a `p` column you have to enter mathmode first (via `$...$`). Depending on your use, you may also want to use it with `\displaystyle`.

---

The above answers the question of why what you are doing doesn't work, but it also doesn't mean you should do it that way.

Instead, load the `amsmath` package and use `align` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    E &= mc^2 & F &= ma
\end{align}
\end{document}
```